# May Rationalize produce a decimal output (do nothing) on results of NSolve, Solve//N?

Tags: equation-solving

Here is a perplexing example, which does nothing (yields 0.3) on 11.3,  Windows 10:

```
kn = -1 + s 10/3
cr = s /. NSolve[kn == 0, s, 3]
Rationalize[cr[[1]]]
```

(my initial equation was of third order; Solve yielded complex roots instead of real, NSolve fixed that, but I could not regain "rationality").

Comment: Yes, just remove the `3` at end. `kn = -1 + s 10/3;
cr = s /. NSolve[kn == 0, s];
Rationalize[cr[[1]]]`  Why do you have `3` there?

Comment: "initial equation was of **third order**; `Solve[]` yielded *complex* roots instead of real" - are you aware of *casus irreducibilis*?

Comment: Nasser, the problem is not from the 3, it occurs also on kn = -1 + 10  s ; cr = s /. NSolve[kn == 0, s, 1];Rationalize[cr[[1]]] , the final answer is still .1 Strangely, if I erase the 1 in NSolve, i.e. for cr = s /. NSolve[kn == 0, s],  it disappears. I guess   the problem  must  be specific to version 11.3 on Windows 10, since it seems you do not encounter this

Comment: If `Solve` gave roots containing the complex unit `I` (sqrt(-1), that is), then those roots are not rational. Applying `Rationalize` to the corresponding `NSolve` result will not make the roots rational. It might give rational approximations to them, but they are still algebraic numbers. So you need to be clear about what you want, and to understand what you might be getting.

Comment: From the [`documentation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html), "Rationalize[x] yields x unchanged if there is no rational number close enough to x to satisfy the condition |p/q-x|<c/q^2, with c chosen to be 10^-4." and "Rationalize[x, 0] converts any inexact number x to rational form."

Comment: Thanks, I had missed all these points! I was  in a casus irreducibilis for the third order equation (as suggested by the presence of  the  unnecessary  complex unit in the answer), and sometimes to get fraction approximations with Rationalize you need to add the parameter 0!

Comment: Your last comment suggests that you misunderstood the concept of *casus irreducibilis*: in the case where all three roots of a cubic are real, it is sometimes unavoidable to use complex numbers to represent the results, *if* you insist on a representation in terms of radicals.

Comment: I was imprecise  (sorry ...)  but  I only  insist on the answer being real (as guaranteed by a theorem). So, I  should  have used  NSolve.   It is quite interesting to learn  that the appearance of i when using Solve is due to the probable absence  of  real answers involving radicals